# Expression file.exists() returns true, reading file fails with FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, netbeans-7, filenotfoundexception

Method returns `FileNotFoundException`:

```
String statSource = 'some path';
 try {

         File file = new File(statSource);

         if (!file.exists())
         {
             System.out.println(file.getPath() + " doesn't exist!");
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("OK!");
         }


         // otevření CSV
         csv = new CsvReader(statSource, ';', Charset.forName("windows-1250"));
     }
```

At first I get 'OK!' message, but on the last line I get `FileNotFoundException`. File is located on a local hard drive.

DO you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Your `CsvReader` initialization takes place whether or not the file exists.

Comment: Is the statsource path a directory or a file?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is the most useless exception to ever grace the JDK since you will also get it when the file exists but you cannot read/write it. So, post the full stack trace: only the associated message may give a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about [this class](http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html), and that you are using JDK 7, do yourself a favour and use this:

```
final Path csvpath = Paths.get(statSource);

try (
    final InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(csvpath);
    final CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(in, ';', Charset.forName("windows-1250");
) {
    // operate on csv
}
```

If the file does not exist or whatever, you will at least get a meaningful exception: `AccessDeniedException`, `NoSuchFileException`, etc; all of them inheriting `FileSystemException`.

Comment: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\medm\Documents\Rocenka\Rocenka_2014_test_listopad\Rocenka_2014_priprava\data\2014\2014-oprava_ST055.csv at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79) at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97) at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102) at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:229) at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:315) at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)`

Comment: Well now you know what the problem is ;)

Answer (score 0):

> FileNotFoundException - If the given file object does not denote an
>   existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name
>   cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or
>   creating the file

So a `FileNotFoundException` may be thrown in the following 3 cases.

1. File does not exist.
2. File is actually a directory.
3. **The named file cannot be opened for reading for some reason, say permission**

So, make sure you are operating on a file not a directory, and then try using `file.canRead()`(not reliable enough at windows though, see [bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6203387)) to test it for the #3.

Comment: Even `.canRead()` is unreliable, unfortunately. I've seen it fail on Windows plenty of times.

Comment: @fge, yeah, but worth trying though.I will update it in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are just giving the File name to the csvReader. for reading the Files in java, you have to use, FileReader.

Can you try changing the last line to,

```
csv = new CsvReader(new FileReader(statSource), ';', Charset.forName("windows-1250"));
```